# Recursive method for multiplying arraylist elements

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I hope my wording isn't too confusing. I'm working on a school project regarding recursion. I built a GUI to allow a user to input numbers into the program. I want to store the numbers the user enters into the textField in an array list so that I can use a recursive method to multiply all numbers by themselves. I am able to create the array list and store the numbers, but I can't seem to figure out how to recursively multiply the elements in the ArrayList. I thought I could do something like this:

```
numbers.get(numbers.size()) * (numbers.size() - 1)
```

The above doesn't work because the index is always out of bounds. Not really sure I understand what is happening here either.

I have a separate driver class that calls the GUI class to run the program. See below.

```
public class Gui {
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;
    //Array list to store user input.
    public static List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int num;
    //recursive Method
    public static int calculate(){


        return(0);
    }

    //Gui Program
    public static void addComponents(Container pane){
        if(RIGHT_TO_LEFT){
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }

        JLabel label;
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        if(shouldFill){
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        }
        //Instruction Label
        label = new JLabel("Welcome to recursion! Enter 5 numbers below.");
        if (shouldWeightX){
            c.weightx = 0.5;
        }
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);
        pane.add(label, c);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter Numbers:");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(label1, c);

        JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        //Accepts only numbers 1 - 9. Zero defeats the purpose of the program.
        tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
               tf.getText();
               if(ke.getKeyChar()>='1' && ke.getKeyChar()<='9' || ke.getKeyChar()== KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
                   tf.setEditable(true);
               }else{
                   tf.setEditable(false);
                   label.setText("You must enter numeric digits 1-9");
               }
            }
        });
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 105, 0,10);
        pane.add(tf, c);

        JLabel outLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,10,10,0);
        pane.add(outLabel, c);


        JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
        b.addActionListener(e -> {
            try {

                num = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
                numbers.add(num);
                outLabel.setText(String.valueOf(numbers));
                tf.setText("");

            }catch (Exception x){
                outLabel.setText("Please make sure you have entered a number!");
            }
        });
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(10,25, 10,25);
        pane.add(b, c);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Multiply!");


        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,25, 10,25);
        pane.add(b2, c);

    }

    public static void createGui(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Recursive Multiplication");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponents(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will have to create the logic for the multiply button, something like:

```
  JButton b2 = new JButton("Multiply!");
    b2.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
            int result = multiple_recursive(numbers, 0);
            // choose label to set the value.
              

        }catch (Exception x){
            // solve exception
        }
    });
```

then defined the method to multiply recursively:

```
public static int multiple_recursive(List<Integer> numbers, int count){
    if(numbers.size() == count){
        return 1;
    }
       return numbers.get(count) * multiple_recursive(numbers, count + 1);
}
```

So the idea is you pass the `list` and a `count` variable. This `count` will tell the current position of the list of numbers. For each recursive call you take the current element from the list `numbers.get(count)` and call again recursively but adding one to the current `count`  *i.e.,* `multiple_recursive(numbers, count + 1);`. The recursive calls should stop as soon as the current `count` is the same as the list size, we return 1, because of the multiplicative identity property of that value.

For a list with the element `{5, 2, 10}`. The iterations will be like:

1. numbers.size() == count False
2. return numbers.get(0) * multiple_recursive(numbers, 1);
3. return 5 * (multiple_recursive(numbers, 1));
4. return 5 * (numbers.get(1) * multiple_recursive(numbers, 2));
5. return 5 * (2 * multiple_recursive(numbers, 2));
6. return 5 * (2 * (numbers.get(2) * multiple_recursive(numbers, 3)));
7. return 5 * (2 * (10 * multiple_recursive(numbers, 3)));
8. since numbers.size() == count is True then
9. return 5 * (2 * (10 * 1));
10. return 50

Comment: thank you this explanation helped clarify several things for me. I will need to practice this more to get good at it. I appreciate your assistance.